# Python list-like string representation of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider there is a few rather long numpy arrays:

```
importy numpy as np;
long_array1 = np.array([random.random() for i in range(10000)]);
long_array2 = np.array([random.random() for i in range(10000)]);
long_array3 = np.array([random.random() for i in range(10000)]);
```

I would like to save the arrays into the file `file.dat`, one row per numpy array.
The text representation of an array should be in a python array-like format, i.e. in the case of following numpy array:

```
a = np.array([0.3213,0.145323,0.852,0.723,0.421452])
```

I want to save following line in the file.

```
[0.3213,0.145323,0.852,0.723,0.421452]
```

There is what I do:

```
array1_str = ",".join([str(item) for item in long_array1]);
array2_str = ",".join([str(item) for item in long_array2]);
array3_str = ",".join([str(item) for item in long_array3]);

with open("file.dat","w") as file_arrays:
    file_arrays.write("[" + array1_str + "]\n");
    file_arrays.write("[" + array2_str + "]\n");
    file_arrays.write("[" + array3_str + "]\n");
```

Everything works fine actually. I am just doubtful about the efficiency of my code. I am almost sure there has to be another (better and more efficient) way how to do this. 
I welcome comments to the random list generation as well.

Comment: what's the exact problem you're trying to solve?  What's going to be reading these files?

Comment: I am going to analyze the data later - drawing charts, computing probabilities etc. The problem is that there is already a few modules using the specified format and so I want to keep the format same to make the following processing easier. Nevertheless, what format do you recommend (for my future use)? CSV format would be probably the best for general compatibility. But is there any format which is recommended for use in python (written in file by python, read by python, processed by python...)?

Comment: Aside: you'd usually write `np.random.random(10000)` instead of calling Python's standard random function in a list comprehension and then calling `np.array`.  It's both shorter and faster.

Comment: with or without the list brackets?

Comment: with the brackets... but I guess it's a minor difference... I will edit the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the fastest way:

```
','.join(map(str, long_array1.tolist()))
```

If you want to keep the text more compact, this is fast too:

```
','.join(map(lambda x: '%.7g' % x, long_array1.tolist()))
```

Source: I benchmarked every possible method for this as the maintainer of the pycollada library.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want a Python-list-like format, how about actually using the Python list format?

```
array1_str = repr(list(long_array1))
```

That's going to stay mostly in C-land and performance should be much better.

If you don't want the spaces, take 'em out after:

```
array1_str = repr(list(long_array1)).translate(None, " ")
```

Memory usage may be an issue, however.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you might be able to use the [`numpy.savetxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) for this;

something like:

```
def dump_array(outfile, arraylike):
    outfile.write('[')
    numpy.savetxt(outfile, arraylike, newline=',', fmt="%s")
    outfile.write(']\n')
```

although i don't think the corresponding `numpy.loadtxt()` will be able to read in this format.